# Concatenate a column and drop duplicates in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have several data frames with the same structure:

```
  animal  color       animal color       animal color
0 dog     red       0 dog    blue      0 cat    green
1 cat     red       1 cat    blue      1 mouse  green
2 rat     red       2 horse  blue      2 seal   green
3 mouse   red       3 eagle  blue      3 bird   green
```

And I want to obtain a new data frame with only the unique animal values, but a list of all the colors an animal belongs to, so I can analyze the frequency of the animals and the colors

```
  animal color
0 dog    ['red','blue']
1 cat    ['red','blue','green']
2 rat    ['red']
3 mouse  ['red','green']
4 horse  ['blue']
5 eagle  ['blue']
6 seal   ['green']
7 bird   ['green']
```

Alternatively, a data frame like the last one, can I make a 'reversed' data frame?

```
  color animals
0 red   ['dog','cat','rat','mouse']
1 blue  ['dog','cat','horse','eagle']
2 green ['cat','mouse','seal','bird']
```

I need the values as lists, so I can apply `len()` to them and get a integer. I can't seem to find a way to wrap my head around the problem for several hundreds of files.

I tried concatenating all data frames together, and then filtering by 'color', but I seem to have got lost along the way.

Answer (score 1):

Concat then group the dataframe by animal and aggregate color with unique

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('animal', as_index=False)['color'].unique()
```

To make a reversed dataframe, Concat then group the dataframe by color and aggregate animals with unique

```
pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('color', as_index=False)['animal'].unique()
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the DFs, groupby either 'animal' or 'color' (your 'reversed' df) and calculate the length

````
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(animal=['dog', 'cat', 'rat'], color=3*['red']
                             )
                   )

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(animal=['dog', 'cat', 'horse'], color=3*['blue']
                             )
                   )

df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=dict(animal=['cat', 'mouse', 'seal'], color=3*['green']
                             )
                   )


# Concatenate DFs
concat_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])

# Groupby animal and get unique colors per animal
grouped_df = concat_df.groupby('animal', as_index=False)['color'].unique()

# Count frequency
grouped_df['freq'] = grouped_df['color'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

  animal               color  freq
0    cat  [red, blue, green]     3
1    dog         [red, blue]     2
2  horse              [blue]     1
3  mouse             [green]     1
4    rat               [red]     1
5   seal             [green]     1

# Or for your 'reversed' df

reversed_df = concat_df.groupby('color', as_index=False)['animal'].unique()

# Count frequency
reversed_df['freq'] = reversed_df['animal'].apply(lambda x: len(x))

                   animal  freq
color                          
blue    [dog, cat, horse]     3
green  [cat, mouse, seal]     3
red       [dog, cat, rat]     3
```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['dog', 'cat', 'rat'], 'color': ['red', 'red', 'red']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['dog', 'cat', 'horse'], 'color': ['blue', 'blue', 'blue']})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ['cat', 'mouse', 'seal'], 'color': ['green', 'green', 'green']})
```

**Step1**

concat dataframes

```
dfs = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
```

`dfs`

```
    animal  color
0   dog     red
1   cat     red
2   rat     red
0   dog     blue
1   cat     blue
2   horse   blue
0   cat     green
1   mouse   green
2   seal    green
```

**Step2**

get list of colors by animal

use `unique`

```
dfs.groupby('animal', sort=False)['color'].unique().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    animal  color
0   dog     [red, blue]
1   cat     [red, blue, green]
2   rat     [red]
3   horse   [blue]
4   mouse   [green]
5   seal    [green]
```

**Step3**

get frequency of colors by animal

use `nunique`

```
dfs.groupby('animal', sort=False)['color'].nunique().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    animal  color
0   dog     2
1   cat     3
2   rat     1
3   horse   1
4   mouse   1
5   seal    1
```

**Step4**

get list of animals by color

```
dfs.groupby('color', sort=False)['animal'].unique().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    color   animal
0   red     [dog, cat, rat]
1   blue    [dog, cat, horse]
2   green   [cat, mouse, seal]
```

**Step5**

get frequency of animals by color

```
dfs.groupby('color', sort=False)['animal'].nunique().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    color   animal
0   red     3
1   blue    3
2   green   3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to analyze frequencies, don't use lists as intermediates, this is inefficient.

You could just [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])
out = pd.crosstab(df['color'], df['animal'])
```

Or, if many dataframes, first `crosstab`, then aggregate:

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
out = reduce(lambda a,b: a.add(b, fill_value=0),
             (pd.crosstab(x['color'], x['animal']) for x in dfs)
            ).fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Output:

```
animal  cat  dog  horse  mouse  rat  seal
color                                    
blue      1    1      1      0    0     0
green     1    0      0      1    0     1
red       1    1      0      0    1     0
```